# Getting nil when adding GMSMapView from storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I decided to create a view in my storyboard and defined its class to `GMSMapView`. Then I created an `IBOutlet` to my `ViewController` class.

But when I try to add a camera to my `GMSMapView`, I'm getting a nil value in the `IBOutlet` object:

```
let camera: GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 48.857165, longitude: 2.354613, zoom: 8.0)
newMapView.camera = camera
```

What's happening?

Comment: Where are you writing this code? Try writing it in viewDidLoad. The outlet may not be set till the time you are accessing it.

Comment: I am writing that in my `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @JaysonTamayo can you shoe your code?

Comment: Please share your code and what error you get

Comment: Is that issue fixed @JaysonTamayo

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code..**

```
var mapView_: GMSMapView!
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: centerLat, longitude: centerLng, zoom: centerZoom)
mapView_ = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.allplacemapview.bounds, camera: camera)
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
var startLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theAppDelegate.lang, theAppDelegate.long1)
self.setMarker(mapView_, imageName: "startPoint.png", location: startLoc, titleString: "Current Location")
self.allplacemapview.addSubview(mapView_)
```

Comment: var mapView_: GMSMapView!
var camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: centerLat, longitude: centerLng, zoom: centerZoom)
mapView_ = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.allplacemapview.bounds, camera: camera)
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
var startLoc = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(theAppDelegate.lang, theAppDelegate.long1)
self.setMarker(mapView_, imageName: "startPoint.png", location: startLoc, titleString: "Current Location")
self.allplacemapview.addSubview(mapView_)